# Write jQuery functions inside angnular component file(.ts) in angular 8

Tags: jquery, angular, angular8

**I'm using Angular version 8.**
In my angular 8 project, I'm going to use the [bootstrap-input-spinner](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap-input-spinner) package. I installed the package using `npm install -save bootstrap-input-spinner` command and package is successfully installed. Also I added the js reference to the `angular.json` file as below.

```
"scripts": [
  "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
  "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
  "node_modules/popper.js/dist/popper.min.js",
  "node_modules/bootstrap-input-spinner/src/bootstrap-input-spinner.js"
]
```

As the [bootstrap-input-spinner](https://shaack.com/projekte/bootstrap-input-spinner/) documentation says, I have to call the following jquery function in my page.

```
<script>
    $("input[type='number']").inputSpinner();
</script>
```

I executed `npm i @types/jquery` command and added `import * as $ from 'jquery';` to my component file. Then I called this jQuery function in ngInit() method as below

```
  ngOnInit() {
    $("input[type='number']").inputSpinner();
  }
```

After adding this when I build the project it gives me following compilation error.

```
ERROR in src/app/views/view-products/view-products.component.ts:14:31 - error TS2339: Property 'inputSpinner' does not exist on type 'JQuery<HTMLElement>'.

14     $("input[type='number']").inputSpinner();
```

My questions are.

1. What is the best way to do this.
2. How can I call this jQuery method in my component file.

Comment: Can you please reinstall the package using --save option and change the line in angular.json like ./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js.

Comment: @RBC9662, I already tried that way.  After adding the 'import * as $ from 'jquery';'  to the component file, $ sign is identifying and there is a new compilation error. I updated my post with the compilation error I'm getting now.

Comment: npm install --save @types/jqueryui
please import 'jqueryui'; try this